# Apache GraphX Partiton Strategy is generating error

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am trying to use the road network dataset of SanFranciso that is freely available in this link:

cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/SpatialDataset.htm

I am using the Edge Dataset only and I want to partition the road network map on a cluster of 3 machines (for now). However, when I try to apply 'graph.PartitionBy(PartitonStrategy)' function on the graphRDD, I get the error as 'Partition strategy is cannot be resolved or is not a field'. Can anybody suggest why I am getting the error? I will put the code below:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("graph");
    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    

    ClassTag<String> stringTag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(String.class);
    ClassTag<Integer> intTag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Integer.class);
    ClassTag<Double> doubleTag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Double.class);

    List<Edge<Double>> edges = new ArrayList<>();
    String inputFileName = "Dataset/SFEdge.txt";

    // Edge datset contains edgeId|SourceId|DestinationId|EdgeLength
    // edges.add(new Edge<Double>(1, 2, 3.5));
    // edges.add(new Edge<Double>(2, 3, 4.8));
    

    readTextEdgeFile(edges, inputFileName);

    JavaRDD<Edge<Double>> edgeRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(edges);

    Graph<String, Double> graph = Graph.fromEdges(edgeRDD.rdd(), "", StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY(),
            StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY(), stringTag, doubleTag);

    
    graph.edges().toJavaRDD().foreach(x -> System.out
            .println("Source: " + x.srcId() + " , Destination: " + x.dstId() + ", Distance: " + x.attr$mcD$sp()));

    //Error is generated here below this comment
    graph.partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.RandomVertexCut$.MODULE$);

}

public static boolean readTextEdgeFile(List<Edge<Double>> edgeList, String txtFileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String line = "";
    String txtSplitBy = " ";
    boolean removedBOM = false;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFileName))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] record = line.split(txtSplitBy);
            if (record.length == 4) {
                if (!removedBOM && record[0] != "0") {

                    record[0] = String.valueOf(0);
                    removedBOM = true;

                }
                edgeList.add(new Edge<Double>(Integer.parseInt(record[1]), Integer.parseInt(record[2]),
                        Double.parseDouble(record[3])));

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the dependency version. I think the newer version of GraphX could not find the partition Strategy. Hence, I changed my dependencies to a lower version and it worked.
`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-graphx_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

`
By the way is there any way to find that the graph has been partitioned? Sort of validation?